# how to store current day into a variable using unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to store the day of currrent date into variable and then use in a **IF** condition to run specific commands on specific days.
I have used date +'%u' but it's not helping me.

Comment: This isn't clear. What part are you having trouble with? Assigning to a variable, or getting `date` to output the info you want? *I have used date +'%u' but it's not helping me.* isn't very specific. Why isn't it helping you? Give an example of what you want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
day=$(date +'%u')
if [ "$day" -eq "4" ]; then 
    echo "Today is Thursday"; 
else
    echo "Today is not Thursday"
fi
```

If you want to refer to the day of the year, change `%u` to `%j`, or to `%d` to get the day of the month.

Of course the variable `day` could also be inlined.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect